# Dynamic import with webpack

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, dynamic-import

I have a trouble implementing a dynamic import (I might just have a lack of understanding the concept).

I have a `vue.js` application written in `typescript` with a `webpack`. All frameworks are last stable versions. I'd like this application to support plugin components. The plugin is defined in application configuration and then loaded with a dynamic import and can be shown somewhere.

I set up two separate configurations in Webpack config, one for the app, another for the plugin:

`webpack.config.js`:

```
...
var main = Object.assign({
        entry: {
           Home: './ViewModels/Home/main.ts'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "./Scripts/dist/"),
            filename: "[name].js",
            chunkFilename: '[name].js'
        },
    },
    vueJsConfig);

var testChunkConfig = Object.assign({
        entry: {
           TestChunk: './ViewModels/Test/registrations.ts'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "./Scripts/dist/"),
            filename: "[name].js",
            chunkFilename: '[name].js'
        },
    },
    vueJsConfig);


module.exports = [main, testChunkConfig];
```

`~/ViewModels/TestChunk/registrations.ts':

```
import Vue from "vue";
Vue.component('testExternal', require('./testExternalComponent.vue').default);
```

`~/ViewModels/Home/main.ts':

```
...
let test = "TestChunk";
import(test);
...
```

Usage:
`~/ViewModels/Components/ProjectAdministration/Test/projectAdminTest.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Test Page</h2>
        <testExternal></testExternal>
    </div>
</template>
```

Unfortunately, this shows an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'TestChunk'
    at eval (eval at ./ViewModels/Home lazy recursive
```

Comment: there is a `babel` plugin called `dynamic-import` to dynamicaly import plugins into your app, is this used?

Comment: @NikosM. No, I've never heard of it. I'll try to read more about it, but in my head, I should not have a need to use any build plugins, dynamic import should be sufficient

Comment: try reading t his: https://medium.com/js-dojo/code-splitting-with-vue-js-and-webpack-c9830b29d557 and yes, you need @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import at the end.

Comment: @PlayMa256 Ok, I've tried to follow the article, and I seem to succeed, but unfortunately, this is not what I want. Looks like Babel/Webpack need to process chunks before being able to find them. By that I mean generate `0.js` (or `bundle.0.js` in article) out of my `TestChunk.js`. This is good for code splitting but unappliable in my case. I want to be able to upload `TestChunk.js` to a production server and server should grasp this file. This means that webpack will build `Home.js` and `TestChunk.js` separately and it doesn't know about `TestChunk.js` when it builds `Home.js`

Comment: dynamic `import` is NOT supported for `import` directives (only static `import`) maybe babel plugin has some workaround, else try to use dynamic `require` if possible. `require` can be dynamic but works in node, else simply add the script tag dynamicaly in your web page